# Nginx how to pass a parameter to proxy server?

Tags: nginx

I have a very simple problem but I am new to nginx so I may be missing some obvious solution.

So I have a location defined in nginx

`/example/$id`

I would like to pass $id to parametrized route on my proxy server like so

`http://server.com/example/$id`

This gives me unknown id variable on nginx reload. So my question is how can I pass a parameter from nginx to my proxy server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all the rest are correctly set, you can just create a location with a regex and pass the captured variable to your proxy.

```
location ~ ^/example/(.+)$ {
  proxy_pass http://server.com/example/$1;
}
```

If your `$id` is numeric only, the regex could be more restrictive

```
location ~ ^/example/(\d+)$ {
  proxy_pass http://server.com/example/$1;
}
```

Note that you can't just use a variable without declaring it first. Declaring $id is not necessary, it is captured inside the parentheses of the regex and passed to `$1`

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to bind it to a a specific variable if I don't want to use regex?

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma the request is bound to variable `$uri`. If `/example/` is the same in your proxy and your location, you can use `location /example/ { proxy_pass http://server.com$uri; }`, but otherwise I don't see how you could read the variable `$id` without a regex